# Reporting LaTeX error at custom location

Tags: errors, packages, package-writing, latexmk, compilation-error

I'm familiar with `\PackageError` as a way to cause LaTeX to report a custom error message when the command is run. But I'm wondering, is there a way to cause LaTeX to report an error, with a custom filename and location?

I run my .tex files through an external preprocessor, and when that preprocessor fails, I'd like to have my editor (vscode Latex-workshop) report the error inline. My thinking is that, if the preprocessor fails, I can have it generate a "dummy" file that calls `PackageError` reporting the location of the preprocessing error.

I also use latexmk, so if there's a way to do this using its tools, that would work too.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "no".  But it is a bit hard to understand so perhaps I misunderstood the question. If you want to generate an error that says it is made on line 100 of foo.tex you _could_ generate a 100 line text file which is blank except for a `\PackageError` on line 100, but I don't think you mean that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's what I'm trying to avoid. I'll generate the 100-line file if I have to, but I'd rather a command that says "output the error as if I'd generated a 100 line file".

Comment: well it depends who or what the error is for, you can of course simply `\typeout` exactly that message and then throw a `\errmessage` to cause an error, but you may need to fake tex's format more or less exactly if for example you want an existing editor error log parser to pick it up